# Moving boards between projects

Tags: azure-devops

I need a little advice.

We have a few projects in Azure DevOps, and I need to move a Board and all it's work items, regardless of status, from one project into another project.  So basically lifting and shifting it.

Is there an easy way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

> Moving boards between projects

You could use bulk move:

1. Create new query to select all work items [Create and save managed queries with the query editor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/queries/using-queries?view=azdevops&tabs=new-nav):

[image]

2. Select all work items in the query result and select move:

[image]

3. Select your new team project:
   [image]
4. Save all work items.

Comment: The only down side of moving them in bulk is that all of the work item state will be reset to new. But if you need bulk move, that is the best you get.